weird negative sign in a state vector in qiskit
I run the following simple code in qiskit, which get statevector of a quantum circuit.
qc = QuantumCircuit(3)
qc.initialize(
    [
        0.0 + 0.0j,
        sqrt(1 / 3) + 0.0j,
        0.0 + 0.0j,
        0.0 + 0.0j,
        0.0 + 0.0j,
        0.0 + 0.0j,
        0.0 + 0.0j,
        sqrt(2 / 3) + 0.0j,
    ]
)
qc.cry(pi / 2, 1, 0) # (theta, controlled bit, target bit)

print(Statevector(qc))

The output is the following:
Statevector([ 0.        +0.j,  0.57735027+0.j,  0.        +0.j,
              0.        +0.j,  0.        +0.j,  0.        +0.j,
             -0.57735027+0.j,  0.57735027+0.j],
            dims=(2, 2, 2))

I expected that the sign of |011> = |6> is plus, however it seems minus....
Am I wrong? or What is the problem here?
Thank you in advance!

We start with the state, $$\sqrt{1/3}|001\rangle + \sqrt{2/3}|111\rangle$$
Then apply $R_y(\pi/2)$ to the first qubit controlled by the second qubit. By linearity, we can calculate the impact of applying this gate to each basis state individually.
The basis state $|001\rangle$ will not impacted since the second qubit in state $|0\rangle$. On the other hand, the basis state $|111\rangle$ will be impacted.
We have,
$$
R_y(\theta) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} \cos(\theta/2)&-\sin(\theta/2) \\ \sin(\theta/2)&\cos(\theta/2) \end{array}} \right)
$$
Multiply the state of the first qubit by this matrix when $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$,
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{array}} \right) \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} 0 \\ 1 \end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{array}} \right)$$
So, the final state will be,
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} |001\rangle- \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} |110\rangle+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} |111\rangle$$

Thank you so much for clear and detailed answer. It saved my time and I was completely confused. Appreciated!
